# How to add a custom field in Amazon Connect Customer Profiles e.g. CallTag?

Tags: amazon-web-services, shopify, amazon-connect

I have done `Amazon Connect Customer Profiles` integrations with Shopify but it's only mapping `FullName, Email, and Phone` of Shopify with Customer Profiles.

I want to implement `After Contact Work` as adding/assigning `CallTags` with the profiles but i am unable to find any `Object` to use within `Customer Profiles`. So, after some R&D i got to know that i have to create a custom object in Customer Profiles and then use `Show View` block in my contact flow and use `DisconnectFlowForAgentUI` attribute.

It will bring the after contact work page once call ends with a list of callTags, The agent will select `one or more then one callTags` and on submit i want to call `UpdateProfile` API to add the selected callTags in my customer profile.

The ultimate goal is to add callTags in customer profiles and we can search the customer profiles by callTag.